# Problem with integrity constraint in hibernate (JpaRepository) when updating a register

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables in a database, A and B. Defined in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
id NUMBER,
Name VARCHAR(100),
  CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE B (
id NUMBER,
a_id NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT id_a_id FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)
);
```

What I want to do is using JpaRepository update a register "lets suppose with id:5" of the A table when the B table have a register with a_id:5.

To do that, the first think y tried is to get the entity from the A database, modify the Name value, delete the old register and save a new one with the changes:

```
@Transactional
void update()
{
 List<A> oldARegisterList = a.findById(5);
 A oldARegister = oldARegisterList.get(0);
 A newRegister = new A(oldARegister);
 a.delete(oldARegister);
 newRegister.setName("NewName");
 a.save(newRegister);
}
```

But I was getting a ORA-02291: integrity constraint (id_a_id) violated - parent key not found.

Then I have tried to delete the register in B, delete and create the register in A with the new name and finally create again the register in B:

```
@Transactional
void update()
{
 List<A> oldARegisterList = a.findById(5);
 A oldARegister = oldARegisterList.get(0);
 B oldBRegister = oldARegister.getB();
 b.delete(oldBRegister);
 A newRegister = new A(oldARegister);
 a.delete(oldARegister);
 newRegister.setName("NewName");
 a.save(newRegister);
 b.save(oldBRegister);
}
```

An it dosen't work ether giving the same problem, but if I execute manally first the deletion of B register, then the update of the A register and finaly the recreation of the B register it works.

So it seems that if the process of delete B update A and recreate B is in the same transaction, the process does not work.

How it is possible to do that in the same transaction?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you want to perform delete operation? Why don't you simply set the name in your oldARegister object and commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first note I should notice that you can simple update `oldARegister` name without deleting `oldBRegister` because name is not primary key on A so just use this:

```
oldARegister.setName("New Name");
a.save(oldARegister);
```

But if you want to do it on your way, you should set A of `oldBRegister` to `newRegister` like this:

```
oldBRegister.setA(newRegister)
b.save(oldBRegister);
```

Comment: @codeLover The problem is that with this I get a ORA-02291: integrity constraint

Comment: @david.t_92 you should set foreign key to the newly object created. that's why you are getting integrity constraint

Comment: As simple as change the object with the changed variable and save it!

Thank you a lot!